# GeoServer authentication and MapFish plugin

Tags: geoserver, printing, mapfish-print

I am using the MapFish GeoServer plugin for printing maps from GeoServer. It was working just fine.

For security reasons, I added an authentication plugin that needs an "authkey" parameter to access the layers. The problem is that I am not able to pass the parameters while printing the pdf. And I could not find any alternative method.

The example URL of the WFS layer with "authkey" is:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/reflect?format=application/openlayers&layers=world:worldmap&authkey=authkeyhere
```

And the URL for printing is:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/worldmap.pdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by passing authkey parameter in the url above like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/worldmap.pdf?authkey=authkeyhere
```